# Raspberry unbootable after unexpected shutdown

Tags: raspbian, linux, power, boot-issues

I have a raspberry Pi, Model B.

I installed Raspbian on the SD card and I would like to use it as a SVN server.
The problem is that when it shuts down unexpectedly (i.e. there is a blackout, or DC power gets accidentally disconnected before shutting down the OS), it won't boot anymore. It hangs on a black screen and doesn't boot up. How can I fix this?

Comment: try UPS (uninterruptible power supply).

Comment: What is it? Like a battery which starts working when the DC power is lost?

Comment: Yes. [More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of a corrupted file system after an unexpected shutdown. I used a Linux system with an SD card reader and used the `fsck`(check and repair Linux filesystems) tool to "repair" the file system.

There are LiveCDs/LiveUSBs with Linux so you don't need to install the entire OS if you don't want to.

After that, I made a image of the working SD card, so I am able to simply rewrite the whole SD card in case something happens later.

Comment: Ok, but that is really boring. With a normal computer, this doesn't happen, I can't believe there isn't a way to get rid of this problem

Comment: "Normal computers" don't use an sd card to store all OS files. [See this for a way to stop sd card corruption](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/how-can-i-prevent-my-pis-sd-card-from-getting-corrupted-so-often)

Comment: I use the SD-Card for boot only. The OS and the data are located on a usb-stick. @KevinBrey Thank you for the link, didn't thought of making the boot-partition read-only ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's a known issue where if the Pi loses power; it can corrupt the SD card permanently. I've lost 2 so far.  The best way to avoid this is to either use a UPS; or, as I do, keep it plugged into a cheap netbook with a 9 hour battery.

Comment: Can you provide sources for this? Is there an explanation why SD cards get destroyed so often in the Raspberry PI, but not in other devices?

Comment: Other than personal experience there's this thread tells more; there are a lot of theries such as if the card is genuine, if you are overclocking the Pi, and even if it's class 4 vs 10:            http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=36533