# Should I be worried if my SD card has been corrupted?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, fsck

#### Summary

My Pi has crashed a few times recently. I'm investigating ways to make it stop, but I'm also concerned that there are immediate implications to my file system.

#### Background

After one crash, I couldn't boot the Pi properly. It complained of filesystem corruption, so I ran `fsck` on both SD card partitions. It could then boot, but several services didn't run. For example, `apache2` wouldn't start, complaining that there was no group `www-data`.

I noticed that `/etc/groups` was now a symlink pointing to `../init.d/<something_I_forget>`. I restored it, and the Pi now started fine.

How could this file get corrupted in such a strange way? Also, I am now concerned that other files are similarly corrupted, and I'll only notice later down the track. Is this possible? Can I check, or should I restore an older backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat common if your Pi shuts down unexpectedly (perhaps from low voltage) or crashes, or even if you shut it down without stopping Apache gracefully - if this is going to be a common occurrence, you may want to set it up such that the SD card is in read-only mode

alternatively, different file systems have different anti-corruption implementations, and some may be better than others.

Unfortunately detecting a corrupt file is rather difficult to do without trying to actually use the file, and trying to use the file may not occur until "somewhere down the track".

[see here fore more info](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8038/19227)

Comment: I agree.  I'm to the point that I wish the pi had 2 CF card slots so that you could mount the OS and /home separately.  As it is after most changes I backup the whole card up to NAS.  Since I have extreme NAS storage available I've thought about setting up a cron back up but haven't done it yet.

Comment: @Tyson - you can mount different partitions separately (on the same SD card, provided it has sufficient capacity), and move the home location to a separate partition. see [here](http://mike632t.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/resizing-partitions/)

Comment: I've since noticed other corruption. I ran `sudo raspi-config`, and was told `insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01nmbd`. OTOH, read-only access to the SD card seems too complicated for me. I need to write frequently to `/var/www` and numerous other directories. I'd be excluding so many directories that they would be at risk of corruption anyway.

Comment: @Tyson FWIW I restored from a `backintime` image, which worked perfectly. I have a cron job to back up nightly. I could then just `rsync -aEHAXP --del` the `/` and `/boot` directories back to the SD card, and was good to go.